# Table or CSS for Aligning Images in Signature

Tags: html, css

Can anyone advise and perhaps sample code to arrange the images below please ? It's for a html signature with linked images but i'm unsure whether tables or CSS would be best.

Image Far Left should align with the other 4 horizontally and the two top images need to be centered above the larger images below.

Any help appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47lxQ.jpg)

Comment: What you have done so far? any code?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never design layout with tables. Tables are for displaying table data, and not for layout. When you say "html signature", you mean for emails? It's unclear. Email signatures might be better designed with tables due to the way different email programs parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using css is better than table.I think you want something like this. but you should scale your images by width and height properties:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>goodarzi</title>

</head>
<style>
.first{
 float:left;
 width:30%;
 text-align:center;

}
</style>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="first">
 <a href="" ><img src="" title="" /></a>
 </div>

 <div class="first">
 <div>
 <a href=""><img src="" title="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div><a href=""><img src="" title="" /></a>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="first">
 <div>
 <a href=""><img src="" title="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div><a href=""><img src="" title="" /></a>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes email signature. I have tried to encourage text based but have been over-ruled and supplied with 5 images to be arranged as per image.

Comment: i think the code i have written, solve your problem. whats wrong exactly?

Comment: Hi Farhad, It's great many thanks. I just have a couple more questions. Am I able to reduce the white space between the first image and the group of 4 ? Secondly am I able to slightly increase the white space between the top 2 and bottom 2 images ? Could I use CSS Padding ?